# Search and replace many caracters in a group in VS2013

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm looking for an expression to archive this :

```
Find:       resMgr.GetString("Button.Annuler")
Replace by: Labels.Button_Annuler
```

Actually I tried this expressions

```
Find:       resMgr.GetString\("(.+)"\)
Replace by: Labels.$1
```

The result is Labels.Button.Annuler, it does not replace the . by _

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two separte groups.

Find:       `resMgr.GetString\("([^."]*)\.(.*)"\)`

Replace by: `Labels.$1_$2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will work only if I have one . in the searched expression, do you think we could find a solution to work on resMgr.GetString("Button.Annuler.Tooltip.Detailed")